# SQL: what is wrong in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains 3 tables (student, class and student_class). In the class table there are some classes that have their delete time set to NOT NULL. I want to update the delete time of the student of these classes to the current time.

The short table schema is as follows:

student(id, name, ..., delete_time)

class(id, name, ..., delete_time)

student_class(id, studentId, classId)

the query i tried :

```
    UPDATE student SET delete_time = now() WHERE id IN ( 
        SELECT student.id FROM student, student_class,class WHERE
            student.id = student_class.studentId AND
            student_class.classId= class.id AND
            class.delete_time IS NOT NULL
```

but it did not work i got an error says :

> #1093 - Table 'tbl_student' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data, is there anything with query ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove student from "FROM" clause?

Comment: I do not see `tbl_student` anywhere, and you are missing a closing parenthesis.  What is the target database system (SQL Server?  MySql? Oracle?

Comment: If you're using MySQL it's a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494

Comment: Probably MySQL with its that stupid limitation that you cannot reference the table that you are updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you would do this using `update` with `join`:

```
update student s join
       student_class sc
       on s.id = sc.studentid join
       class c
       on c.id = sc.classid
    set s.delete_time = now()
    where c.delete_time is not null;
```

Notes:

- The error you get is specific to MySQL; you cannot modify a table and include it in a subquery.
- Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Because you could have multiple links between different students and classes in your student_class you can't create a cross-table by selecting `FROM` multiple tables. You could create a nested `SELECT`

```
UPDATE student s SET s.delete_time = now() WHERE s.id IN (
  SELECT sc.student_id from student_class sc where sc.student_id = s.id AND sc.class_id IN (
    SELECT c.Id FROM Class c WHERE sc.class_id = c.id AND delete_time IS NULL
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks for your help your query updated only one student. the first i got works well